# How to convert raw hex char[] to ascii string - C++ Dotnet

Tags: arrays, .net, byte, c++-cli

I am modifying some existing code that sends and receives data via USB. The data is typed into a textbox in ascii format, converted to raw data ie '1' = 01h and then sent to a USB handler.

I have the following code to convert from a string to hex:

```
    String^ TestString = TxDataTB->Text;

    //Prepare a USB OUT data packet to send to the device firmware

    //convert to a byte array
    Encoding^ ascii = Encoding::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
    array<Byte>^ TxHexData = ascii->GetBytes(TestString);
    cli::pin_ptr<UCHAR> pin_ptr_n = &TxHexData[0];
    UCHAR* ptr_n = pin_ptr_n;

    //Now send the USB packet data in the OUTBuffer[] to the device firmware.
    USBHandler->SendData(ptr_n, Msglength, PipeNo);
```

That seems to do the job OK, I have tested this with a breakpoint (no hardware yet!).
I am struggling to find a method to convert the received data to a string^ - getBytes only appears to work with data that is already in an encoded format; Convert only seems to work with an array^ and I can't even find a way to convert a char[] to an array^ Sending the data in ascii format is not an option in this application

Comment: It's not clear to me what type of conversion you're looking for. Could you provide an example of an *exact* input string and what it would convert to? Do it in the form of `String^ input = "foobar"; array<Byte>^ expectedOutput = gcnew array<Byte> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`

Comment: I want to convert an array like this: 
unsigned char input[] = {0x01, 0xAA,0x55};
into:
String^ output = "01AA55"

Comment: Use BitConverter::ToString(input).  You'll get - dashes between the byte values, String::Replace() to remove them.